# C# UUID Version 4 standalone generator and UUID validation

Tags: c#, postgresql, mono, guid, uuid

For my distributed storage keys I want to use UUID v4, and .NET Framework's `System.Guid` gives me exactly that. However, I cannot test right now if Mono gives the same v4? Is there a standalone v4 generator in C#/F#? Is there a spec that says that .NET/Mono GUID is always version 4? (googled, couldn't find)

Additionally, I want to do some hack with GUID v4. Given that the format of it is `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`, I want to replace the **4** with a custom HEX number. I need this to embed a kind of epoch info when my GUIDs was generated in my system, and I know that the max number of epochs will never reach HEX `f`.

The question is if that is safe and future proof? Are you aware of any software that somehow validates Guids in a way other than 'it must be some 128 bits'? I am afraid that putting e.g. 5 instead of 4 could break something in, e.g. PostgreSQL uuid column type or in some similar situation. And I cannot test all cases where that could happen. I tested all numbers instead of 4 with `System.Guid.Parse()` and it works OK, but I do not know if that is by luck or by spec.

Comment: Obviously, porting mono source took less than 10 minutes... The second part is still a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the UUID specs at 
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

I quote (this is under the v4 section):

Conformance with URN Syntax:
      The string representation of a UUID is fully compatible with the
      URN syntax.  When converting from a bit-oriented, in-memory
      representation of a UUID into a URN, care must be taken to
      strictly adhere to the byte order issues mentioned in the string
      representation section.

Validation mechanism:
      Apart from determining whether the timestamp portion of the UUID
      is in the future and therefore not yet assignable, there is no
      mechanism for determining whether a UUID is 'valid'.

** I presume that if no validation is possible, no software should complain about your manually generated UUID, as long as the timestamp is future

Comment: Thanks! Interesting to know if any software actually does this validation. The spec only says that this is only possible way, but doesn't say it is mandatory. `System.Guid.Parse` eats happily a GUID from future

Comment: Probably you should start googling about the strictness of the UUID spec on several platforms and base your software on that research.

Comment: Given that v4 is completely random and v6+ could be whatever - it is unlikely that anyone does validation. I will stop actively researching here, thanks!